# I need an API to update the repositories branch field

Tags: bamboo

I have one bamboo plan that has two repositories repo1, and repo2.
Repo1 branch points to the master and Repo2 branch points to develop.
But that plan has multiple plan branches like release_1_0_0, release_1_1_0, etc, and here each plan branch repo's point to branch release_x_x_x.
Now when I create new bamboo plan branches the repo's branches point to default branches. manually we can update it, but I want to update the branch using API call so that it's point to different branch that I want using API call.
The field that I want to update using API call you can see in the pic given below.
[image]
[image]

I tried going though the doc -> https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-bamboo/REST/8.2.4/#d2e2335
And also https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bamboo/rest/api-group-api/#api-api-latest-repository-repositoryid-scan-status-get
couldn't find the answere.